# Permanently print ajax reply with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

**Context**

Ajax code is used to fetch data from an Sql database, so when a new message is inserted into a database that message is printed into a HTML div.

**The Problem**

The problem is that when the variable is inserted into the div, it replaces the existing value of the div. One possible solution is too send the whole chat log every time, however I would prefer to avoid this for obvious reasons!

**Client Side Code**

```
var newmessages = function () {
    setTimeout(newmessages, 5000);

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxtesting.php",
        type: "GET",            
        dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        if(msg !== null && msg !== "") {
            $("#chat").html(msg);   
            scroll();
        }


    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });   
}
```

The message variable is used to store the Ajax response and the line:

```
 `$("#chat").html(msg);`
```

Is used to print the value to the div "chat".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("#chat").append(msg);
```

If you need to insert new message in top then

```
$("#chat").prepend(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append to `#chat` rather than using `html()`.

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out jQuery's append() function: http://api.jquery.com/append/

This way you can append the result of the Ajax call.